# TFS 2012 : Capacity Calendar / overview

Tags: tfs

Currently we're experimenting with TFS2012. We're new to agile, but love it right away. Anyway, what we're looking for is cross-project / cross-sprint resource planning facility.

To be more specific, if I work in multiple projects simultaneously, I need a view for my superiors to show them how busy I am. Something very much like this :

[image]
Now I know that TFS has all the data required for that. Does such a thing exist? Or would I have to develop a plugin myself?

EDIT: Since this has been answered, I posted a [follow-up detail question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990421/tfs-11-2012-api-questions-query-capacity-and-days-off).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen anything with such a feature, however [using the api to access iteration dates](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2012/05/28/tfs-api-part-47-vs11-manage-iterations-dates.aspx) to generate an iCal which can be imported to an exchange calendar seems fairly easy.