# how to import capacity data from excel to microsoft team foundation server 13?

Tags: tfs, import-from-excel, capacity

it is easy to export tfs data to excel, but i wonder how to get the data from excel imported to capacity of tfs scrum 2013. by capacity, i mean the team member, capacity per day something like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible at all.

You can use the API to access this information through the TeamSettingsConfigurationService as per [TFS 11 2012 API Questions : query capacity and days off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990421/tfs-11-2012-api-questions-query-capacity-and-days-off)

Comment: could you be more specific? by not possible you mean there is no direct way to do that? What api i can use? i am pretty new to tfs. Thanks!

Comment: previous i write a console application to read data from excel and store the data into ms project object, so you mean something like this?