# TFS Capacity plan reading from c#

Tags: c#, tfs, wiql

Am doing a reporting tool out of tfs. i was able to read the work item and iteration related information from tfs. How to get the iteration capacity plan information from tfs. using WIQL or any other option. i need to get the information in my c# code.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: And what've you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not able to do this through Client Object Model. Please refer this similar question:  [TFS 11 2012 API Questions : query capacity and days off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990421/tfs-11-2012-api-questions-query-capacity-and-days-off)

*These values are only available from the Server Object Model (there is no Client Object Model equivalent at the moment). The interfaces and objects are all made `Internal` so even on the server you can't access these values.*

> `internal TeamCapacity GetTeamIterationCapacity(Guid teamId, Guid iterationId);`
>
> Declaring Type: `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.WorkItemTracking.Common.DataAccess.TeamConfigurationComponent`
>
> Assembly: `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.WorkItemTracking.Common, Version=12.0.0.0`

You could either  directly query from the ProjectCollection database from the tables mentioned by *James Tupper* in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21485566/5391065).

Or you could also use **Rest API** to  [Get a team's capacity](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/work/capacity#get-a-teams-capacity) or [Get a team member's capacity](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/work/capacity#get-a-team-members-capacity) will get a response as below:

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "teamMember": {
        "id": "8c8c7d32-6b1b-47f4-b2e9-30b477b5ab3d",
        "displayName": "Chuck Reinhart",
        "uniqueName": "fabrikamfiber3@hotmail.com",
        "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/Identities/8c8c7d32-6b1b-47f4-b2e9-30b477b5ab3d",
        "imageUrl": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_api/_common/identityImage?id=8c8c7d32-6b1b-47f4-b2e9-30b477b5ab3d"
      },
      "activities": [
        {
          "capacityPerDay": 0,
          "name": null
        }
      ],
      "daysOff": [],
      "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/6d823a47-2d51-4f31-acff-74927f88ee1e/748b18b6-4b3c-425a-bcae-ff9b3e703012/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/2ec76bfe-ba74-4060-970d-4567a3e997ee/capacities/8c8c7d32-6b1b-47f4-b2e9-30b477b5ab3d"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iteration objects are part of Project settings, you might need to query the iteration details from there and not from work item.